# The relation between "substitute" and

Tags: etymology

..."prostitute". Both words are suffixed by "-stitute", but obviously the meaning are quite different. "Substitute" is a conceptual, mental and intelligent activity, whilst "prostitute" is a profitable, body (mostly) and sensual activity. In my opinion, they don't have any reasonable relationships! So why do they spell so similar?

Comment: *restitution, destitute, constitute, institute, prostitute,* and *substitute* all derive ultimately from the same [Latin verb](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=statuere&searchmode=none). Prostitute: *that which is put before* → *that which is offered for sale* → *those who sell themselves*. Substitute: *that which is put under* → *that which is put in place of* → *those who replace others*.

Comment: Although your comment is far more clearer than the answer, I still feel your pointers jumping too fast. However with reading your comment and the answer I think I have got the idea. Thanks you both!

Comment: Re: your title. I think that's something the substitute would prefer to keep private. ;-)

Comment: Like my latest edit? :)

Comment: No, it's not a good edit.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

They are related by *situation*. Both are derived from the Latin root word, to stand.

One stands before (exhibited), one stands under or next to (in place of).

[prostitute](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=prostitute):
from Latin *prostitutus*, (expose publicly, as in for sale) from **pro-**: *before*  + **statuere**: cause to stand, establish, to put, place.

Used from the 1520s, to offer to indiscriminate sexual intercourse (usually in exchange for money).

**substitution**: from Latin; put in place of another, place under or next to, present, submit, from **sub** "under"  + **statuere**: *set up, to stand* with derivatives meaning *place or thing that is standing*

Used since late 14c., appointment of a subordinate or successor

Answer (score -1):

All those words derive from Latin statuere, which in turn derives from the word stare (to stand). This goes back to an Indo-European root *sta and so relates to words like German stunden.

Comment: Related to German stehen/stand/gestanden, not related to stunden.

Comment: Can you cite references?